# How to use different environment variables during React development? axios/webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios, react-scripts

I want to be able to use the command line to specify which environment I am using during development. I have created different environment variables and files that have the details for each (.env, .env.development, etc). And so far, when I run `npm run start` it will default to the `.env.staging` file configurations, and I presume the `npm run build` will default to production configurations. But I want to be able to use either production/development/production urls/details when in development mode.

For example:
`npm run start development`
`npm run start staging` or `npm run start production`. How can I achieve this with what I have so far?

In my package.json file I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "jest test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "clean": "rm -rf build artifacts",
    "artifact-package": "./artifact-package.sh",
    "resources": "capacitor-resources -p android,ios"
  },
```

My .env file

```
REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID=yyy
REACT_APP_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID=xxx
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://my-api-production.io/
```

My .env.development file

```
REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID=yyy
REACT_APP_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID=xxx
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://my-api-development.io/
```

Webpack:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: "process/browser",
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
     })
    ],
  };
};
```